# sometimes get error processing my request in my dataTask

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlrequest

I am using `URLSession` in my iOS project (Swift 4).

```
var postRequest = URLRequest(url: myUrl)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

let dataTask = defaultSession.dataTask(with: postRequest) { data, response, error in
        if let error = error {
          // Sometimes I get error here
          showError(error.localizedDescription)
        } else if let data = data,
          let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
          response.statusCode == 200 {
          // most of the time, everything is fine
          ...
        }

dataTask?.resume()
```

When I run the code to talk with my server, I normally have no issue, everything works as expected. But sometimes I get non-nil `error`, the `localizedDescription` says `There was an error processing your request`.

I am not sure how to fix this because I don't get more debugging information & this happens only randomly.

Could someone point me to the correct direction, what could cause this error when using `URLSession` talking to server?

Comment: Put `print(error)` before `showError()` and see what you get. Usually `print(error)` shows a little more info (Error Code, for example) than `error.localizedDescription`.

Comment: I will do that, since the error comes randomly, I hope I could reproduce it easily. Thanks. I will test again.

Answer (score 0):

That's a server-side error — likely 500 or 502, but potentially anything.  If you print the error code, you might know a bit more.

Additionally, by default, NSURLSession drops the connection when it gets back an error code, but it is possible to tell it to fetch the error page data (which might contain even more information about what went wrong).

To do this, add a delegate method to the session's delegate, e.g.

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session 
          dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask 
didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response 
 completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionResponseDisposition
                   disposition))completionHandler {
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)httpResponse;
    // For server errors or success status, fetch the response body, else cancel.
    if (httpResponse.statusCode >= 500 && httpResponse.statusCode <= 599) {
        completionHandler(NSURLSessionResponseAllow);
    } else if (httpRepose.statusCode == 200) {
        completionHandler(NSURLSessionResponseAllow);
    } else {
        completionHandler(NSURLSessionResponseCancel);
    }
}
```

Of course, you will also have to create and retain a session (because the default session has no delegate).